# Placement of --force in a force push command

Tags: git

After a rebase, I accidentally used `git push origin --force local` instead of `git push --force origin local`. Instead of pushing the changes to my remote, I got `Everything up-to-date`. Thereafter, using `git push origin local` resulted in `Everything up-to-date`.

I thought it doesn't matter where in the command `--force` is placed. What does `git push origin --force local` do?

EDIT: No, the placement of `--force` doesn't matter. The cause of the `Everything up-to-date` is that I rebased on the wrong branch.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

Comment: Can you show me the section that explains what `git push <remote> --force <local>` does? As opposed to `git push --force <remote> <local>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the documentation, I can find no explanation for how git would interpret the command line you're asking about.

In my tests, it works exactly the same as when `--force` is placed before the remote name.  This would suggest that, in order to get the results you got, I would have to already have the `origin`'s `local` branch at the location to which I'd be `push`ing it.

If the output from the first command was just 'Everything up-to-date`as you describe, and did not include a summary of any ref moves, that again supports the idea that`local` didn't need to move.

I suppose it's possible that an older version of git behaves differently, if you're using an older version of git; but I doubt that's the issue.

In any event, you can check the current state of the branches.  First I'd make sure you have a current look at the remote's refs

```
git fetch
```

Then you can use `git log` to see where the relevant refs are pointing.

```
git log local
git log origin/local
```

Or use `gitk` for a more helpful graphical view

```
gitk local origin/local
```

The simplest explanation would be if your rebase didn't actually change the `local` branch ref.  You can check that with something like

```
git reflog local
```

Comment: Your answer prompted me to investigate my rebase, and it looks like I rebased off the wrong branch, so nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. `git command --option argument` is exactly the same as `git command argument --option` (But not `git --option command argument` — in that case `--option` is an option for `git` itself but not for `git command`).

See the docs for GIT Command Line Interface at https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitcli.html or https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcli.